# MIPS Programm (Why is $t3 = 0x0000 0010 )

Tags: mips

Can someoe help me understand why  $t3 = 0x00000010

```
.data   
vec: .word 8, 12, 16, 19, 2009, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0

.text   
main: lw $t1, vec  
lw $t2, vec+4   
lw $t3, vec($t1)   
lw $t4, vec+4($t3
```

Answer (score 0):

Because that `lw $t1, vec` at the beginning loads the first word at `vec` into `$t1`, i.e. 8.

`lw $t3, vec($t1)` then loads the word at `vec+$t1`, i.e. `vec+8`. An offset of 8 gives you the third word, since each word is 4 bytes. And the third word at `vec` is 16, which in hexadecimal notation is 0x10 (those six leading zeroes are of no importance).